# Facebook like page that is behind login

Tags: facebook

I have a lot of images on a page, and for each image I have a facebook like button. This page is behind login (you have to be logged in to view it). Facebook is sharing the link to the root page, becouse I redirect every page behind login to the root page. How can I fix this, to share the link to that page ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page to be liked must be accessible to Facebook scraper without the need to login. You can allow special access to the scraper by detecting it's User Agent:

```
      facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```